# Onclick move div to center and expand

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a bit of a challenge. Here's what I'm looking for:

I have 4 divs to n on my page but only 4 div are visible to users.
When it click on one of the div, the clicked div move to center of the page and expand approximate 80% of page and push other div out of the way.

I've tried using jQuery animation but not succeed.

Any thoughts?

Comment: show some of the stuff what have you tried till.

Comment: show us what you have so far? Definately sounds like jQuery is the best option

Comment: this is i got so far http://jsfiddle.net/t2jjwhb4/

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery code is a simple way to expand your div and push other divs out of the way, maybe it fits into your needs. Check the jsfiddle for the whole code - http://jsfiddle.net/ur9mrxnq/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.expand').click(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            width: '80%',
            left: '10%'
        }, 950);
    });
});
```

Comment: the expand part it ok but when you click on the div i want to move in center not to stay in the same position

Comment: I did it by adding the "left" positioning. If the div has to be 80% width, you'll have 10% each of margin. So, but the div 10% left from his parent and it i'll be centered. You can also add a "margin: 0 auto" css attribute with jQuery, it will also center the div.

$(this).css({margin: "0 auto"});

Comment: And you have to remove the "float" from the targeted div. Check this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/LevelZwo/t2jjwhb4/4/

Comment: I do this : http://jsfiddle.net/t2jjwhb4/5/
but if it's a way to make an animation when i put the div in center?